# How to render dynamic content "component" with custom tabs VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, web-frontend

i have a costume made Tabs and Tab from [Laracasts Tabs Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-95jgDDZq3Y) , and it work fine, but i need to load data when the tab is changed and i did that but when the data is loaded,

i need to render another component which have accordion and inside each accordion tab their some charts components need to be render also

so how can i render the accordion with the charts components when the Tabs tab is changed

**Tabs Component:**

```
 <template>

    <div class="tab-container -mt-px w-full">
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul class="list-reset flex border-b">

                <li class="" v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" role="tab">
                    <a class="bg-white inline-block font-semibold hover:no-underline"
                       :class="[
                        {
                           'active-tab-link text-blue-dark  border-l border-r active-tab-link-p': tab.isActive,
                           'text-blue hover:text-blue-darker non-active-tab-link-p': !tab.isActive
                       },
                       ]"
                       :href="tab.href" @click="selectedTab(tab)">
                        {{tab.name}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-details px-4 w-full">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "Tabs",

        data() {
            return {
                tabs: []
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.tabs = this.$children;
            // this.selectFirstTab();
        },

        methods: {

            selectedTab(selectedTab) {

                this.$emit('onTabChange', selectedTab);

                this.tabs.map((tab, index) => {
                    tab.isActive = (tab.name === selectedTab.name)
                });

            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Tab Component:**

```
<template>

    <div class="w-full" role="tabpanel" v-show="isActive">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import {isEmpty} from "../helpers/Helper";

    export default {
        name: "Tab",
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            selected: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
            isFirst: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                // isActive: false,
                isActive: true,
                // isFirst: this.isFirst
            };
        },

        computed: {
            href() {
                return this.formatHref(this.name);
            },
        },

        mounted() {

            this.selectTabFromURL();

        },
        methods: {

            selectTabFromURL() {
                let hash = this.$route.hash;

                if (this.selected) {
                    this.isActive = this.selected;
                } else if (!isEmpty(hash)) {
                    this.isActive = (this.formatHref(this.name) === hash);
                } else if (this.isFirst) {
                    this.isActive = this.isFirst;
                } else if (!this.isFirst && this.isActive) {
                    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
                }
            },

            formatHref(id) {
                return `#${id.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-')}`;
            }


        }
    }
</script>
```

**the main component:**

```
<template>
 <!--components tabs start-->
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <div class="mt-3 border-t-4 border-primary-color border-6 bg-white">
                    <div class=" border border-gray-400 lg:border-l-0 lg:border-t lg:border-gray-400  rounded-b lg:rounded-b-none lg:rounded-r leading-normal">

                        <Tabs @onTabChange="handleTabChange">

                            <!--:name="`${tab.name} - ${tab.component.type}`"-->
                            <Tab v-for="(tab, index) in page.tabs"
                                 :key="tab.id"
                                 :id="tab.slug"
                                 :name="tab.name"
                                 :slug="tab.slug"
                                 :isFirst="index === 0"
                            >

                             <div>
                                 How to render the dynamic accordion with the charts one time only no need to re-render 
                             </div>


                            </Tab>

                        </Tabs>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--components tabs end-->
</template>
```

in normal HTML and JQuery, i can load the data and the render the result and append it to the wanted tab how can we do this with vue, dose the dynamic component help in this case ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if you are looking for `<keep-alive>`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

Comment: @Pradeepb nop i'm not changing components in the parent component, i need to create a component and attached to the right tab content when the tab clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for a solution and found and implement the ["Creating Vue.js Component Instances Programmatically"](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/)